# Security of MATLAB Compiler

Tags: matlab, security, encryption, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I am interested to hear how secure the source code is when compiled with MATLAB Compiler as of 2014? I read two threads on the subject from 2011 that states that there are security flaws.

In this thread from 2011 it is stated that the names of the source files are exposed to the users
http://www.mathworks.fr/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/299373

In this thread from 2011 it is stated that m-files sometimes are exposed at obscure locations in the host system.
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/310932

Do anyone know if these flaws have been addressed?

Comment: Voting to reopen this question - it is really not opinion-based, and is asking a very specific question about a potentially insecure behaviour of MATLAB Compiler, rather than asking for general opinions about its security.

Comment: Yes, I got some solid answers that I am happy with, so I really can't see any gains by editing or re-phrasing the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All applications produced by the MATLAB Compiler (and related toolboxes) include an embedded CTF archive. This archive is embedded in the generated component (standalone EXE, shared DLL, Java packes, .NET assemblies, etc..) along with a target-specific boilerplate code to expose it as a binary component of the expected format.

The CTF archive contains all the MATLAB source and data of the project files in an encrypted form (AES encryption). The archive is extracted when the application runs for the first time (to a configurable cache location), files are then decrypted and executed in the context of the MCR runtime. So even though there will be a bunch of visible M-files inside the cache directory, they all in an encrypted form (no clear text code is ever written to disk).

You can read more about this in [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler/application-deployment-products-and-the-deployment-tool.html#bsfsq0l).

The way I see it, there is no glaring flaw here, and there never was... I don't think the names of the source files is something one worries about exposing!

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have two questions concerning the "visible M-files inside the cache directory". Can they be extracted so that the separate (encrypted) file can be used in any way on its own (e.g. calling it and receiving output)? Do I understand it correct that the names of the source files are exposed?

Comment: Yes, the names of the source files (and the names of any subdirectories they are stored in) are visible in the temporary extraction directory. All the MATLAB source code files are encrypted and no, (other than by breaking the AES encryption) there is no way that they can be used or called by anything other than the compiled application that they are part of.

Comment: @Amro I don't have access to MATLAB Compiler any more, so can't check this. But if you have access, perhaps you can confirm whether files _other than .m files_ are encrypted when included within an application. I half-remember that they are not - but perhaps I'm misremembering. cont...

Comment: ...If I'm right that they are not encrypted, then that's something you need to be careful of - for example, you may be including `.mat` files of proprietary data in your application. In addition, your MATLAB preferences directory is wrapped up in the archive, which is stored in regular text files, not `.m` files, and could be looked through.

Comment: @SamRoberts: yes that's right (I haven't checked it yet, but I remember it so as well); MAT-files in the project were not encrypted, also the contents of `prefdir()` were included unencrypted as well. A workaround for the preferences part was to create a temporary MATLAB profile used to package applications (by setting `MATLAB_PREFDIR` environment variable before starting MATLAB), that way none of my actual settings were exposed

Comment: @SamRoberts: Ok I just tried it myself, and what you said above holds. One exception though: if you have M-files in the `prefdir` (like `run_commands.m`), it is encrypted in the output component, everything else from the preferences folder is not. In addition, if you have a M-script (part of the project) containing only comments (like a `Contents.m` file) it will be packaged unencrypted. Tip: if you have a program like 7zip installed, you can just open the binary component produced (DLL library in my test), and see the CTF archive contents for yourself.

Comment: It looks like the archive is in an OpenXML format (like Microsoft Office documents .docx, .xlsx, etc.., a zipped XML-based format containing the encrypted source files)

Comment: Yes, that's as I remembered then. I always thought this was a bit of a potential problem with MATLAB Compiler. For example, as well as `history.m`, which would become encrypted, the preferences directory also contains `History.bak`, a backup file of of the command history which, since it's not an m-file, would not be encrypted. From that file you could easily guess, for example, the names of all the companies I consult for and probably what things they're working on. If you care about that sort of issue, be careful to use a clean profile when compiling.